# Google+ Sign-in for Android cannot resolved com.google.android.gms.plus.Plus

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-api-client, google-signin

I try to create a connection google+ in my android application like this [tutorial](https://developers.google.com/+/quickstart/android#install-sdk)
but I'm stuck here

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
    .addApi(Plus.API, null)
    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
    .build();
```

erreur :com.google.android.gms.plus.plus cannot resolved

Version of Android Studio: 0.4.6
OS version: Windows 7 Ultimate 64 bits

I integrated google play service like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16624827/android-studio-with-google-play-services?answertab=votes#tab-top)

[image]

Comment: But can you use the other classes from com.google.android.gms.plus?

Comment: Check whether you have this in your sdk `$Android SDK\extras\google\m2repository\com\google\android\gms\play-services\4.0.30`

Comment: @LuisAlberto yes all other library as in the picture

Comment: Look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21170839/2958420
Also this one will be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17243377/2958420

Answer (score 0):

To be sure that you put the correct library try to see if the build.gradle compile your library in dependencies section.
Remove your library add again with right click add as library.
Build-> clear project
build again
hope this help