# Problems with SlidingMenu integration

Tags: android, android-studio, slidingmenu

I have been trying to use the SlidingMenu library in my Android Studio project following the guide provided in this question:

[How to import slidingmenu on Android Studio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079072/how-to-import-slidingmenu-on-android-studio)

I've been able to obtain the described file structure and sync&build the project without errors. Yet, when trying to import the Sliding Menu to my apps source files, I'm getting a symbol resolve error.

```
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.SlidingMenu; // Error message: Cannot resolve symbol 'SlidingMenu'
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.BuildConfig;
```

The second import is the only one suggested by Android Studio but I can't even find the BuildConfig file in my project when following the given path.

What do I need to change to be able to import all the classes in `com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib` to my own classes?

My apps gradle files looks like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.me.appname"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile project(':libraries:SlidingMenu')
}
```

The SlidingMenu gradle file:

```
buildscript {
    // define the repo which is to use
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    // define the classpath for Gradle Android Plugin
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.+'
    }
}

// declaring that the project is a library
apply plugin: 'android-library'

// declaring all dependencies the project needs
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:19.0.0'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        // this values you can read out from the Manifest (but I add the right values for you)
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    // because Android Studio has a different file structure than Eclipse
    // you have to say Android Studio where the files are located
    sourceSets{
        main{
            java.srcDirs = ['src/main/java']
            res.srcDirs = ['src/main/res']

            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }
}
```

Project settings gradle:

```
include ":libraries:SlidingMenu", ':app'
```

Comment: Have you tried using its AAR port? https://github.com/jzaccone/SlidingMenu-aar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get the [AAR port of the library](https://github.com/jzaccone/SlidingMenu-aar) (v1.3).

The GitHub Pages is down, so you'll have to import [that AAR](https://github.com/jzaccone/SlidingMenu-aar/blob/gh-pages/com/jeremyfeinstein/slidingmenu/library/1.3/library-1.3.aar) manually:

Top *build.gradle* file:

```
repositories {
    flatDir {
        dirs 'libs'
    }
}
```

Place the AAR file in the *libs* folder of your module, then in your module *build.gradle* file:

```
dependencies {
    compile(name:'library-1.3', ext:'aar')
}
```

Comment: Will the existing SlidingManu library interfere with the AAR version or can I leave all it's content in the project before testing AAR? @shkschneider

Comment: It shares the same packageName (via a github link actually), so it will probably lead to conflict indeed. Only use the AAR version.

Comment: Your solution works! Thanks again for your help, this has been bugging me for a couple of days now, finally I can proceed! @shkschneider

Comment: Glad it solved your issue. Thanks to that AAR port. Feel free to accept my answer to close that question ;)

Comment: Gradle compiled ok but I am not being able to import classes. Any clue?

Comment: @shkschneider what if we are using eclipse for the same problem?