# something error to using SlidingMenu make application in android studio. Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

well,this is  my first time use android studio, and I import SlidingMenu according to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19079072/how-to-import-slidingmenu-on-android-studio) tutorial.I think it is successed.but when I coding,I have something problem that I can't fix. I think maybe someone can help me.this is logcat.

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.chenjiayao.news/com.chenjiayao.news.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2187)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2236)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:138)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1199)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5034)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:807)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:623)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class fragment
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:716)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:472)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:400)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:353)
at com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity.setBehindContentView(SlidingFragmentActivity.java:83)
at com.chenjiayao.news.MainActivity.initSlidingMenu(MainActivity.java:20)
at com.chenjiayao.news.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:16)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5246)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2151)
... 11 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: name == null
at java.lang.VMClassLoader.findLoadedClass(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.findLoadedClass(ClassLoader.java:350)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:487)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:457)
at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.isSupportFragmentClass(Fragment.java:455)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.onCreateView(FragmentManager.java:2135)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreateView(FragmentActivity.java:300)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:688)
... 20 more
```

and there is menu.xml file

```
<fragment
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/menu">
</fragment>
```

and this is MenuFragment.java

```
import android.app.Fragment;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.chenjiayao.news.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MenuFragment extends Fragment {

    private View view;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.lv);

        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<>(getActivity(),
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1,
                initData());

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    private ArrayList<String> initData() {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add("fragment1");
        list.add("fragment2");
        list.add("fragment3");
        list.add("fragment4");
        list.add("fragment5");
        return list;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        view = LayoutInflater.from(getActivity()).inflate(R.layout.list_view,
                null);
        return view;
    }
}
```

last,is MainActivity.java file

```
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import com.jeremyfeinstein.slidingmenu.lib.app.SlidingFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SlidingFragmentActivity{

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initSlidingMenu();
    }

    private void initSlidingMenu() {
        setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        SlidingMenu sm = getSlidingMenu();
        sm.setShadowWidthRes(R.dimen.shadow_width);
        sm.setShadowDrawable(R.drawable.shadow);
        sm.setBehindOffsetRes(R.dimen.slidingmenu_offset);
        sm.setFadeDegree(0.35f);
        sm.setTouchModeAbove(SlidingMenu.TOUCHMODE_FULLSCREEN);
        sm.setBehindScrollScale(0.0f);
        MenuFragment menuFragment = new MenuFragment();
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.menu, menuFragment, "Menu").commit();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

I know problem maybe happen in setBehindContentView(R.layout.menu);,but I don't how to fix it,and more strange is I can run application well in Eclipse.Is wrong way to import SlidingMenu in android studio ? I hope someone can help me fix this problem. th

Comment: `SlidingMenu` is technically deprecated. You should be using the Navigation Drawer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_view, container, false);
    return v;
}
```